# Convert datetime to europe default without time

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, datetime, date-format

I have a datetime field that I need to convert into the format DDMONYY (27Aug12).  I am currently using `convert(nvarchar(30),DateToConvert,13),` but that also spits out the time.  How can I easily convert a date to the format I need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of your hack with replace, why not just cast to the right data type? This doesn't need to be nvarchar and the only reason it contains time is because you included too many characters. You can of course apply your replace here as well (or you could do that at the client).

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(11),GETDATE(),13)
UNION ALL
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(11), DATEADD(DAY, 10, GETDATE()), 13);
```

Results:

```
27 Aug 2012
06 Sep 2012
```

Answer (score 2):

After a little bit more research I found the answer [on the Microsoft cast and convert page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).  The date format 106 is the closest format to what I desire, except that it has spaces in it.  Adding a replace to get rid of the spaces gets it into the proper format.

```
replace(convert(nvarchar(30),DateToConvert,106),' ','')
```

Comment: Strictly, speaking, the `6` format specifier gives a closer result to what you are asking about than the `106` one does, but keeping the century may be a good idea.